# FFMPEG: cannot play MPEG4 video encoded from images. Duration and bitrate undefined

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, x264, mpeg-4, libavformat

I've been trying to set a H264 video stream created from images, into an MPEG4 container. I've been able to get the video stream from images successfully. But when muxing it in the container, I must do something wrong because no player is able to reproduce it, despite ffplay - that plays the video until the end and after that, the image gets frozen until the eternity -.

The ffplay cannot identify Duration neither bitrate, so I supose it might be an issue related with dts and pts, but I've searched about how to solve it with no success.

Here's the ffplay output:

```
~$ ffplay testContainer.mp4
ffplay version git-2012-01-31-c673671 Copyright (c) 2003-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  7 2012 20:32:12 with gcc 4.4.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-        libfaac --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-debug=3
  libavutil      51. 36.100 / 51. 36.100
  libavcodec     54.  0.102 / 54.  0.102
  libavformat    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 60.100 /  2. 60.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[h264 @ 0xa4849c0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000
[h264 @ 0xa4849c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, h264, from 'testContainer.mp4':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 512x512, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
       2.74 A-V:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=  160KB sq=    0B f=0/0   0/0
```

### Structure

My code is C++ styled, so I've a class that handles all the encoding, and then a main that initilize it, passes some images in a bucle, and finally notify the end of the process as following:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

MyVideoEncoder* videoEncoder = new MyVideoEncoder(512, 512, 512, 512, "output/testContainer.mp4", 25, 20);
if(!videoEncoder->initWithCodec(MyVideoEncoder::H264))
{
    std::cout << "something really bad happened. Exit!!" << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
}

/* encode 1 second of video */
for(int i=0;i<228;i++) {

    std::stringstream filepath;
    filepath << "input2/image" << i << ".jpg";

    videoEncoder->encodeFrameFromJPG(const_cast<char*>(filepath.str().c_str()));

}

videoEncoder->endEncoding();

}
```

### Hints

I've seen a lot of examples about decoding of a video and encoding into another, but no working example of muxing a video from the scratch, so I'm not sure how to proceed with the pts and dts packet values. That's the reason why I suspect the issue must be in the following method:

```
bool MyVideoEncoder::encodeImageAsFrame(){
    bool res = false;


    pTempFrame->pts = frameCount * frameRate * 90; //90Hz by the standard for PTS-values
    frameCount++;

    /* encode the image */
    out_size = avcodec_encode_video(pVideoStream->codec, outbuf, outbuf_size, pTempFrame);


    if (out_size > 0) {
        AVPacket pkt;
        av_init_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.pts = pkt.dts = 0;

        if (pVideoStream->codec->coded_frame->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
            pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pVideoStream->codec->coded_frame->pts,
                    pVideoStream->codec->time_base, pVideoStream->time_base);
            pkt.dts = pTempFrame->pts;

        }
        if (pVideoStream->codec->coded_frame->key_frame) {
            pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        }
        pkt.stream_index = pVideoStream->index;
        pkt.data = outbuf;
        pkt.size = out_size;

        res = (av_interleaved_write_frame(pFormatContext, &pkt) == 0);
    }


    return res;
}
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

P.S. The rest of the code, where config is done, is the following:

```
// MyVideoEncoder.cpp

#include "MyVideoEncoder.h"
#include "Image.hpp"
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_AUDIO_PACKET_SIZE (128 * 1024)



MyVideoEncoder::MyVideoEncoder(int inwidth, int inheight,
        int outwidth, int outheight, char* fileOutput, int framerate,
        int compFactor) {
    inWidth = inwidth;
    inHeight = inheight;
    outWidth = outwidth;
    outHeight = outheight;
    pathToMovie = fileOutput;
    frameRate = framerate;
    compressionFactor = compFactor;
    frameCount = 0;

}

MyVideoEncoder::~MyVideoEncoder() {

}

bool MyVideoEncoder::initWithCodec(
        MyVideoEncoder::encoderType type) {
    if (!initializeEncoder(type))
        return false;

    if (!configureFrames())
        return false;

    return true;

}

bool MyVideoEncoder::encodeFrameFromJPG(char* filepath) {

    setJPEGImage(filepath);
    return encodeImageAsFrame();
}



bool MyVideoEncoder::encodeDelayedFrames(){
    bool res = false;

    while(out_size > 0)
    {
        pTempFrame->pts = frameCount * frameRate * 90; //90Hz by the standard for PTS-values
        frameCount++;

        out_size = avcodec_encode_video(pVideoStream->codec, outbuf, outbuf_size, NULL);

        if (out_size > 0)
        {
            AVPacket pkt;
            av_init_packet(&pkt);
            pkt.pts = pkt.dts = 0;

            if (pVideoStream->codec->coded_frame->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
                pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pVideoStream->codec->coded_frame->pts,
                        pVideoStream->codec->time_base, pVideoStream->time_base);
                pkt.dts = pTempFrame->pts;
            }
            if (pVideoStream->codec->coded_frame->key_frame) {
                pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
            }
            pkt.stream_index = pVideoStream->index;
            pkt.data = outbuf;
            pkt.size = out_size;


            res = (av_interleaved_write_frame(pFormatContext, &pkt) == 0);
        }

    }

    return res;
}






void MyVideoEncoder::endEncoding() {
    encodeDelayedFrames();
    closeEncoder();
}

bool MyVideoEncoder::setJPEGImage(char* imgFilename) {
    Image* rgbImage = new Image();
    rgbImage->read_jpeg_image(imgFilename);

    bool ret = setImageFromRGBArray(rgbImage->get_data());

    delete rgbImage;

    return ret;
}

bool MyVideoEncoder::setImageFromRGBArray(unsigned char* data) {

    memcpy(pFrameRGB->data[0], data, 3 * inWidth * inHeight);

    int ret = sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize,
            0, inHeight, pTempFrame->data, pTempFrame->linesize);

    pFrameRGB->pts++;
    if (ret)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool MyVideoEncoder::initializeEncoder(encoderType type) {

    av_register_all();

    pTempFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    pTempFrame->pts = 0;
    pOutFormat = NULL;
    pFormatContext = NULL;
    pVideoStream = NULL;
    pAudioStream = NULL;
    bool res = false;

    // Create format
    switch (type) {
        case MyVideoEncoder::H264:
            pOutFormat = av_guess_format("h264", NULL, NULL);
            break;
        case MyVideoEncoder::MPEG1:
            pOutFormat = av_guess_format("mpeg", NULL, NULL);
            break;
        default:
            pOutFormat = av_guess_format(NULL, pathToMovie.c_str(), NULL);
            break;
    }

    if (!pOutFormat) {
        pOutFormat = av_guess_format(NULL, pathToMovie.c_str(), NULL);
        if (!pOutFormat) {
            std::cout << "output format not found" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }


    // allocate context
    pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    if(!pFormatContext)
    {
        std::cout << "cannot alloc format context" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    pFormatContext->oformat = pOutFormat;

    memcpy(pFormatContext->filename, pathToMovie.c_str(), min( (const int) pathToMovie.length(), (const int)sizeof(pFormatContext->filename)));


    //Add video and audio streams
    pVideoStream = AddVideoStream(pFormatContext,
            pOutFormat->video_codec);

    // Set the output parameters
    av_dump_format(pFormatContext, 0, pathToMovie.c_str(), 1);

    // Open Video stream
    if (pVideoStream) {
        res = openVideo(pFormatContext, pVideoStream);
    }


    if (res && !(pOutFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&pFormatContext->pb, pathToMovie.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
            res = false;
            std::cout << "Cannot open output file" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    if (res) {
        avformat_write_header(pFormatContext,NULL);
    }
    else{
        freeMemory();
        std::cout << "Cannot init encoder" << std::endl;
    }


    return res;

}



AVStream *MyVideoEncoder::AddVideoStream(AVFormatContext *pContext, CodecID codec_id)
{
  AVCodecContext *pCodecCxt = NULL;
  AVStream *st    = NULL;

  st = avformat_new_stream(pContext, NULL);
  if (!st)
  {
      std::cout << "Cannot add new video stream" << std::endl;
      return NULL;
  }
  st->id = 0;

  pCodecCxt = st->codec;
  pCodecCxt->codec_id = (CodecID)codec_id;
  pCodecCxt->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
  pCodecCxt->frame_number = 0;


  // Put sample parameters.
  pCodecCxt->bit_rate = outWidth * outHeight * 3 * frameRate/ compressionFactor;

  pCodecCxt->width  = outWidth;
  pCodecCxt->height = outHeight;

  /* frames per second */
  pCodecCxt->time_base= (AVRational){1,frameRate};

  /* pixel format must be YUV */
  pCodecCxt->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;


  if (pCodecCxt->codec_id == CODEC_ID_H264)
  {
      av_opt_set(pCodecCxt->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
      av_opt_set(pCodecCxt->priv_data, "vprofile", "baseline", 0);
      pCodecCxt->max_b_frames = 16;
  }
  if (pCodecCxt->codec_id == CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO)
  {
      pCodecCxt->mb_decision = 1;
  }

  if(pContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
  {
      pCodecCxt->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
  }

  pCodecCxt->coder_type = 1;  // coder = 1
  pCodecCxt->flags|=CODEC_FLAG_LOOP_FILTER;   // flags=+loop
  pCodecCxt->me_range = 16;   // me_range=16
  pCodecCxt->gop_size = 50;  // g=250
  pCodecCxt->keyint_min = 25; // keyint_min=25


  return st;
}


bool MyVideoEncoder::openVideo(AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *pStream)
{
    AVCodec *pCodec;
    AVCodecContext *pContext;

    pContext = pStream->codec;

    // Find the video encoder.
    pCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(pContext->codec_id);
    if (!pCodec)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot found video codec" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Open the codec.
    if (avcodec_open2(pContext, pCodec, NULL) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot open video codec" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}



bool MyVideoEncoder::configureFrames() {

    /* alloc image and output buffer */
    outbuf_size = outWidth*outHeight*3;
    outbuf = (uint8_t*) malloc(outbuf_size);

    av_image_alloc(pTempFrame->data, pTempFrame->linesize, pVideoStream->codec->width,
            pVideoStream->codec->height, pVideoStream->codec->pix_fmt, 1);

    //Alloc RGB temp frame
    pFrameRGB = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    if (pFrameRGB == NULL)
        return false;
    avpicture_alloc((AVPicture *) pFrameRGB, PIX_FMT_RGB24, inWidth, inHeight);

    pFrameRGB->pts = 0;

    //Set SWS context to convert from RGB images to YUV images
    if (img_convert_ctx == NULL) {
        img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(inWidth, inHeight, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                outWidth, outHeight, pVideoStream->codec->pix_fmt, /*SWS_BICUBIC*/
                SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (img_convert_ctx == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize the conversion context!\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;

}

void MyVideoEncoder::closeEncoder() {
    av_write_frame(pFormatContext, NULL);
    av_write_trailer(pFormatContext);
    freeMemory();
}


void MyVideoEncoder::freeMemory()
{
  bool res = true;

  if (pFormatContext)
  {
    // close video stream
    if (pVideoStream)
    {
      closeVideo(pFormatContext, pVideoStream);
    }

    // Free the streams.
    for(size_t i = 0; i < pFormatContext->nb_streams; i++)
    {
      av_freep(&pFormatContext->streams[i]->codec);
      av_freep(&pFormatContext->streams[i]);
    }

    if (!(pFormatContext->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE) && pFormatContext->pb)
    {
      avio_close(pFormatContext->pb);
    }

    // Free the stream.
    av_free(pFormatContext);
    pFormatContext = NULL;
  }
}

void MyVideoEncoder::closeVideo(AVFormatContext *pContext, AVStream *pStream)
{
  avcodec_close(pStream->codec);
  if (pTempFrame)
  {
    if (pTempFrame->data)
    {
      av_free(pTempFrame->data[0]);
      pTempFrame->data[0] = NULL;
    }
    av_free(pTempFrame);
    pTempFrame = NULL;
  }

  if (pFrameRGB)
  {
    if (pFrameRGB->data)
    {
      av_free(pFrameRGB->data[0]);
      pFrameRGB->data[0] = NULL;
    }
    av_free(pFrameRGB);
    pFrameRGB = NULL;
  }

}
```